# Is it possible to use logical AND in C-Type for loop condition in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have bash script as follows:

```
  for ((; i < $var1  && $str1 -eq $str2; i++))
  do
    str2=$(command1)      
  done
```

That causes following error:

line 110:  i < 5  && path -eq path: syntax error in expression (error token is "path")

I also tried following variations, but similar `sintax error` occurs:

```
  for ((; [ i < $var1 ] && [ $str1 -eq $str2 ]; i++))
  for ((; [[ i < $var1 ]] && [[ $str1 -eq $str2 ]]; i++))
  for ((; [[ i < $var1  && $str1 -eq $str2 ]]; i++))
```

I need to know if it is possible to use logical operator in condition section (2nd part) of C-Type for loop in bash? If yes, how I must correct my script? And if not, what is the solution?

Comment: `-eq` never compares strings, only integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `(( ... ))`, the three expressions separated by semi-colons are all evaluated as arithmetic expressions. However, `-eq` is *not* an operator recognized in an arithmetic expression; it is an integer comparison operator in *conditional* expressions. Compare:

```
$ [[ 3 -eq 3 ]] && echo equal
equal
$ (( 3 == 3 )) && echo equal
equal
$ (( 3 -eq 3 )) && echo equal
bash: ((: 3 -eq 3 : syntax error in expression (error token is "3 ")
```

The C-style `for` loop is similar to, but not identical to, the `for` loop in C. In order to compare strings, you would need to go through some contortions to convert the result of the string comparison to an integer, and compare *that* to another integer.

```
for (( i=1; i < 3 && $([[ $str1 = $str2 ]]; echo $?) == 0; i++)); do
    echo $i
done
```

Here, the command substitution is re-evaluated each time through the `for` loop, and produces a 0 if the `=` evaluates to true and 1 if it evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff in `(( ))` is evaluated in **arithmetic** context, so string comparison is really a non-starter:

```
$ i=1 var1=4 str1=foo str2=bar
$ (( i < var1 && str1 == str2 )) && echo y || echo n
y
```

Here $str1 ("foo") and $str2 ("bar") are both evaluated as numbers (treated as zero) and hence are equal

Just pull string stuff out into the loop body.

```
for ((; i < $var1; i++))
do
    [[ "$str1" != "$str2" ]] && break
    str2=$(command1)      
done
```

Comment: There's no string comparison here, but `-eq` is not a recognized operator in arithmetic expressions, only in conditional expressions.

Comment: I'm assuming, by the variable names, that the values are strings not numbers.

Comment: Yeah, it's a separate misconception on the part of the OP to try using `-eq` here.